# .NET Core Antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens for the wrong user after HttpContext.SignIn is called

Tags: c#, .net-core, csrf

I've been using the Antiforgery Cookie for .NET Core (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery) and I'm always returning a new View after the login:

```
// - HomeController.cs
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity("myAuthType");
    ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync("myScheme", principal,
        new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
            AllowRefresh = true,
            IsPersistent = true
        });

    return View();
}
```

The code is done so that each call/view generates a new X-XSRF-Cookie and sends to the browser, who sends the value back for some Api calls.
The code for that is:

```
// - Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = CrossSiteAntiForgery.Header);
    services.AddMvc(o => {
        o.Filters.AddService(typeof(CrossSiteAntiForgery));
    });
}

// - CrossSiteAntiForgery.cs
public class CrossSiteAntiForgery : ResultFilterAttribute
{
    public const string Cookie = "XSRF-TOKEN";
    public const string Header = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";

    private IAntiforgery _antiforgery;
    public CrossSiteAntiForgery(IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        _antiforgery = antiforgery;
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        AntiforgeryTokenSet tokens = _antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context.HttpContext);
        context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(Cookie, tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });            
    }
}
```

But I wanted to login via Ajax just because. So I kept everything and changed just the Login:

```
[HttpPost("Api/User/Login"), ValidateAntiForgeryToken, Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
    var userFromDB = DB.GetUser(1);

    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity("myAuthType");
    ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync("myScheme", principal,
        new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
            AllowRefresh = true,
            IsPersistent = true
        });

    return Json(userFromDB);
}
```

However now I get errors (Bad Request) because the XSRF tokens don't match. After some (a lot actually) digging, I think I found the issue, the browser does receive the `Set-Cookie` header properly from the ajax and sets the new cookie value, but this value is invalid because it seems whenever the `_antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext)` is called, it uses the current User to generate the token somehow.
When I return a new View, the Context is updated with the new (logged in) User, the token is generated and sent to the browser and everything works perfectly.
When I use ajax and call `HttpContext.SignInAsync()`, the current User hasn't been updated yet and so the generated token will be invalid for the logged in User.

```
// - Login()
var user = HttpContext.User;
await HttpContext.SignInAsync("Login", principal,
    new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
            AllowRefresh = true,
            IsPersistent = true
        });
var loggedInUser = HttpContext.User;

bool truth = user.Equals(loggedInUser); // - true
// - meaning anything that relies on the new logged in User is invalid from here on.
```

The error message in the .NET console is `The provided antiforgery token was meant for a different claims-based user`. I tried the suggestion [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4953) and it seems hacky, it works only for the second request onwards, meaning users would need to see a first "Bad Request" for every User change (Login and Logout).
How can I get/update the User after it has been logged in so the XSRF token generation works? Or, if there's a better solution, how can I solve this?

**Edit:** I'm working around it for now like this, in case anyone has the same issue:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
    // - Login code omitted for brevity.
    return RedirectToAction("LoginUnelegantWorkaround");
}

public IActionResult LoginUnelegantWorkaround()
{
    var model = DB.FetchModelIWasGoingToReturnBefore();

    return Json(model);
    // - token is properly generated now since User has been updated, everything works
}

// - Same thing needed for Logout
```